# join two strings into a date time format asp classic

Tags: datetime, asp-classic, vbscript

I have two variables X and Y. X has a date as a string(12-Jun-2013) and Y has a time (12:46 pm)
I need to put these two together into a date time format before inserting in into a database. Does anyone know what function I need to use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append your two string, with a space, and use the CDate function to convert the whole thing to a date. So:
`CDate("12-Jun-2013 12:46 pm")` will return the date-time value.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. No exactly what I wanted but it did help me accomplish what I wanted, so thanks